# What is the maximum read length for 125khz RFID card?

Tags: rfid

I have a project that is using a 125Khz RFID cards,dots, stickers.

I need a card reader that has a read length of AT LEAST 4-7 metres.

The reader will collect all tags within that range and check them against an inventory.

I have not been able to find any RFID readers that have this range, and I am not sure if it is at all technically possible.

Does anyone know if this is technically possible with a 125khz RFID?

Comment: Not really on topic for Stack Overflow (but still an interesting question). You could possibly try electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification the maximum range for 120–150 kHz (LF) is 10cm.

Comment: Thanks - but I think there is more too it than that - you'll note the wikipedia entry also says " Generally, the read range of a tag is limited to the distance from the reader over which the tag can draw enough energy from the reader field to power the tag. Tags may be read at longer ranges than they are designed for by increasing reader power. "

Comment: Granted, but I would imagine your chances of extending reader range by an order of magnitude would be limited at best

Comment: Yeah I am thinking that - wrong tool for the job, I think! Looks like I need a more active tag with a higher frequency. I was hoping someone might explain the whys of why it wont work!

Comment: SkyRFID states a range of 1-2m with their 134kHz tags